# Vaadin Combobox returns null

Tags: java, vaadin8

## Vaadin ComboBox returns null

[image: the shown combobox]

there I get the preselected value:

```
 this.binder.forField(this.cmbxStockArea).withValidator((t) -> {

        if (cmbxStockArea.getValue().equals("")) {
            return false;
        }
        return cmbxStockArea.getValue() != null;
    }, "es muss ein Lagerplatz gewählt werden").bind(Stock::getStockArea, Stock::setStockArea);
```

Stock#getStockArea returns just a String.
There I get the the selections.

```
    this.stockPresenter.getStockAreaSelection().getCmbxSelectedStockArea().setDataProvider(DataProvider.fromStream(StreamSupport.stream(f.spliterator(), false)));
```

The Validator is working correctly, I printed out getCmbxSelectedStockArea().getValue() and it is null.

There I do the preselection:

```
this.getCmbxSelectedStockArea().setSelectedItem(getLblSuggestedStockArea().getValue());
```

After selecting the preselection again by hand everything works fine.

Thx for you help.

Comment: [Bug report](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-combo-box-flow) you are talking about is for Vaadin Flow - Vaadin 10/11

Comment: I am using Vaadin 8.

Comment: I found a workaround for my problem, and I created an [issue](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/11157) on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed in Vaadin version 8.1.6.